# Extract Tweets of a User

Tags: twitter, web-crawler

I have to extract around 30000 tweets of a user for analyzing some information. But, first thing is extraction of tweets of only those users who have set their locations in their  profile. I am confused about how to go about to achieve this. Should I use an API or a crawler ?

Comment: The Twitter API won't let you retrieve 30,000 tweets of any user.

Comment: Leave about the number 30000. It would be very helpful , if you can tell me the procedure for the extraction.